# Convert from Ajax to Axios

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, axios

I made a website that was done using JQuery but I am now trying to learn react but not sure how I would use axios to connect with my backend API. Does anyone know the equivalent of this to axios.

```
    $("#log-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/users/login',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'user_name': event.target.inputUsername.value,
                'password': event.target.inputPassword.value
            },
            success: function(token){
                 $(location).attr('href', '/feed' ); // Redirect to logged in page
            },
            error: function(errMsg) {
                swal(
                    'Oops...',
                    errMsg.responseJSON.body,
                    'error'
                )
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Try looking at some basic examples of using axios](https://flaviocopes.com/axios/#post-requests), and come back when you have tried some code and with a specific problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll want to set up a [React controlled form](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Axios utilizes [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you use can use `async/await` inside of a `try/catch` block or use the more traditional `.then/.catch`.

**Note**: Always `catch` your promises. A common mistake among beginning developers is to just assume the server is never going to throw an error. As a result, it can crash the entire application.

After you have set up your controlled form, you'll create a custom `handleSubmit` class method callback with your API call:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = { 
    error: "", 
    password: "",
    username: ""
  }

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // in this case, e.preventDefault() prevents the page from refreshing
  const { username, password } = this.state; // grabs current input values from React state

  axios.post('/users/login', { user_name: username, password: password }) // sends a POST request to "/users/login" with data
  .then(token => { // if the POST request was successful...
     // do whatever you need to do with the token (set it to localStorage or Redux state)
     this.props.history.push("/feed");  // then you'll redirect -- this assumes you're at the parent component AND using react-router-dom
   })
  .catch(err => this.setState({ error: err.toString() })); // if there's an error, you'll set it to state and display it in the render method below  
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      ...etc
      <form>
      {this.state.error && 
         <p>
           This was a problem logging in: {this.state.err}
         </p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change to axios..

```
       axios.post ('users/login', { 
        User_name: event.taget.whatever,
        Password: event.taget.whatever
        })
      .then (response => {
         //whatever you want to do with data you recieved
        };
```